# Merge the centre value and all surrounding values of an array over a specific value in another array?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This question is quite abstract to explain in a title. So my apologies for that. I'm trying to merge a Gaussian kernel over two data points in an array for a kernel density estimation.

As the point of a kernel density estimation is to also sum any overlapping kernels. To make things simple, I've distributed the values evenly so two Gaussian kernels can fit aside each other without any overlapping.

After writing this, i've come to exceed the character limit for stack overflow so I've had to trim the arrays that you see below. To see each array in the full length, please visit this URL https://js.do/code/448834

Gaussian kernel values:

```
const kernel = [0.0000010012331378948806, 0.0000010722046681969416, 0.000001147899227196217, 0.0000012286082418128176, 0.0000013146394976171826, 0.0000014063179475064513, 0.0000015039865533165654, 0.000001608007161276116, 0.0000017187614122055291, 0.0000018366516873606909, 0.000001962102090813225, 0.0000020955594692504055, 0.0000022374944700657156, 0.0000023884026385964733, 0.0000025488055553473936, 0.0000027192520140183837, 0.0000029003192411310286, 0.000003092614158021121, 0.000003296774685933875, 0.000003513471094924077, 0.0000037434073972252973, 0.000003987322785709955, 0.0000042459931180157695, 0.000004520232446863388, 0.000004810894597034758, 0.000005118874789422127, 0.0000054451113124928115, 0.000005790587241445476, 0.000006156332205258995, 0.000006543424201755123, 0.000006952991460711095, 0.000007386214354967505, 0.000007844327359380673, 0.00000832862105736654, 0.00000884044419467562, 0.0000093812057799243, 0.000009952377231288787, 0.000010555494568641264, 0.000011192160650276806, 0.000011864047453240681, 0.000012572898396121833, 0.00001332053070302737, 0.000014108837807296342, 0.000014939791793347624, 0.000015815445874887996, 0.000016737936907530242, 0.000017709487933690657, 0.00001873241075744663, 0.000019809108546842802]
```

The highest y axis value of the kernel is `0.006531646276955685`:

```
console.log(Math.max(...kernel))
> 0.006531646276955685
```

Which is at the index `256`:

```
console.log(kernel.indexOf(Math.max(...kernel)))
> 256
```

The total length of the kernel values is `513`:

```
console.log(kernel.length)
> 513
```

Below is the dataset i'm trying to merge with the `kernel` array. It's an array of booleans.

```
const data = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...]
```

I know it's hard to see but there are actually two `1` boolean values inside this array. The first is at index `256` and the second is at index `769`. The total length of the `data` array is `1026`. So exactly the length of two Gaussian kernels.

The goal is to merge and align the centre value and all the surrounding values of a Gaussian kernel over each `1` boolean value in the `data` array. So in other words, each `1` boolean value contained in the `data` array will be replaced with `0.006531646276955685` (the max Gaussian kernel value), and all the surrounding `0` boolean values in the `data` array will be replaced by the surrounding Gaussian kernel values (which are basically just the values around the centre value of `0.006531646276955685`) per Gaussian kernel.

Desired output:

Before merging

```
console.log(data)
> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...]
```

After merging:

```
console.log(data)
> [0.0000010012331378948806, 0.0000010722046681969416, 0.000001147899227196217, 0.0000012286082418128176, 0.0000013146394976171826, 0.0000014063179475064513, 0.0000015039865533165654, 0.000001608007161276116, 0.0000017187614122055291, 0.0000018366516873606909, 0.000001962102090813225, 0.0000020955594692504055, 0.0000022374944700657156, 0.0000023884026385964733, 0.0000025488055553473936, 0.0000027192520140183837, 0.0000029003192411310286, 0.000003092614158021121, 0.000003296774685933875, 0.000003513471094924077, 0.0000037434073972252973, 0.000003987322785709955, 0.0000042459931180157695, 0.000004520232446863388, 0.000004810894597034758, 0.000005118874789422127, 0.0000054451113124928115, 0.000005790587241445476, 0.000006156332205258995, 0.000006543424201755123, 0.000006952991460711095, 0.000007386214354967505, 0.000007844327359380673, 0.00000832862105736654, 0.00000884044419467562, 0.0000093812057799243, 0.000009952377231288787, 0.000010555494568641264, 0.000011192160650276806, 0.000011864047453240681, 0.000012572898396121833, 0.00001332053070302737, 0.000014108837807296342, 0.000014939791793347624, 0.000015815445874887996, 0.000016737936907530242, 0.000017709487933690657, 0.00001873241075744663, 0.000019809108546842802, 0.000020942078460934107, 0.000022133914298650234, 0.000023387309166355133, 0.000024705058160760758, 0.000026090061063633177, 0.000027545325044505026, 0.00002907396736737866, 0.00003067921809717081, 0.00003236442280141311, 0.000034133045242481636, 0.00003598867005538605, 0.00003793500540590263, 0.00003997588562358771, 0.00004211527380395883, 0.00004435726437388044, 0.00004670608561394057, 0.000049166102131353454, 0.00005174181727667466, 0.000054437875497365937, 0.000057259064621001416, 0.00006021031806066359, 0.0000632967169348375, 0.00006652349209387734, 0.00006989602604488875, 0.0000734198547666476, 0.00007710066940595766, 0.00008094431784664176, 0.00008495680614216054, 0.00008914429980266232, 0.0000935131249270873, 0.0000980697691707815, 0.00010282088253892102, 0.00010777327799590268, 0.00011293393188073315, 0.00011830998411833384, 0.0001239087382165863, 0.0001297376610388642, 0.00013580438234174052, 0.00014211669406751854, 0.00014868254938122047, 0.000155510061441668, 0.00016260750189632018, 0.00016998329908958149, 0.00017764603597437197, 0.0001856044477168515, 0.00019386741898431967, 0.000202443980906469, 0.00021134330770035376, 0.00022057471294965238, 0.00023014764552904443, 0.0002400716851648001, 0.00025035653762298576, 0.0002610120295170303, 0.00027204810272676725, 0.00028347480842147536, 0.00029530230067987634, 0.00030754082970052636, 0.0003202007345965395, 0.00033329243576913194, 0.00034682642685504166, 0.00036081326624350226, 0.0003752635681590851, 0.0003901879933074129, 0.0004055972390814562, 0.0004215020293268802, 0.00043791310366568303, 0.0004548412063781893, 0.00047229707484430675, 0.000490291427545827, 0.0005088349516324718, 0.0005279382900553109, 0.0005476120282721495, 0.0005678666805304793, 0.0005887126757345975, 0.000610160342904543, 0.0006322198962355656, 0.0006549014197679224, 0.000678214851677903, 0.0007021699682020994, 0.0007267763672080761, 0.0007520434514257304, 0.0007779804113547997, 0.0008045962078651243, 0.0008318995545074433, 0.0008598988995536758, 0.00088860240778679, 0.0009180179420615469, 0.0009481530446585413, 0.0009790149184551221, 0.0010106104079379032, 0.0010429459800826869, 0.0010760277051287263, 0.0011098612372753278, 0.0011444517953298284, 0.001179804143337022, 0.001215922571221075, 0.0012528108754719263, 0.0012904723399090798, 0.001328909716556553, 0.0013681252066635658, 0.0014081204419063235, 0.001448896465806959, 0.0014904537154063501, 0.001532792003228134, 0.0015759104995717557, 0.0016198077151728775, 0.001664481484269838, 0.0017099289481152002, 0.0017561465389716584, 0.0018031299646317446, 0.001850874193500863, 0.00189937344028318, 0.0019486211523098193, 0.0019986099965486354, 0.0020493318473345863, 0.002100777774859358, 0.0021529380344584683, 0.002205802056733524, 0.0022593584385466716, 0.0023135949349235526, 0.0023684984519002548, 0.002424055040348798, 0.002480249890814702, 0.0025370673293990485, 0.0025944908147162216, 0.002652502935957217, 0.002711085412086988, 0.002770219092202801, 0.0028298839570789673, 0.0028900591219216502, 0.002950722840355647, 0.003011852509663206, 0.0030734246772929894, 0.0031354150486552538, 0.003197798496217239, 0.0032605490699105675, 0.0033236400088602082, 0.0033870437544422536, 0.003450731964675389, 0.0035146755299484836, 0.0035788445900842712, 0.003643208552736542, 0.003707736113115715, 0.003772395275035007, 0.003837153373266842, 0.003901977097196419, 0.003966832515756696, 0.004031685103626371, 0.004096499768669685, 0.004161240880594242, 0.004225872300800272, 0.004290357413392126, 0.0043546591573201225, 0.004418740059618208, 0.0044825622697003175, 0.004546087594675734, 0.004609277535641261, 0.004672093324905533, 0.004734495964098392, 0.004796446263115965, 0.0048579048798497474, 0.0049188323606459035, 0.0049791891814388225, 0.005038935789501051, 0.005098032645749755, 0.00515644026754812, 0.005214119271938399, 0.005271030419241745, 0.005327134656958544, 0.005382393163901616, 0.005436767394493506, 0.0054902191231579744, 0.005542710488734978, 0.005594204038847548, 0.005644662774148459, 0.005694050192374033, 0.005742330332132143, 0.005789467816351291, 0.005835427895317638, 0.005880176489227022, 0.005923680230179243...]
```

Here's a visual example. The "value" in the diagram just represents a `1` boolean value (the decimal was a typo). And of course in the actual array, `1` boolean values are surrounded by `0` boolean values to complete each kernel length.

[image]

**UPDATE**

To offer more clarity. Although overlapping is excluded from this task. The goal will be to apply this method to cases with overlapping. I don't expect to work that out here, but it's important that the goal of merging is achieved in the manner described. Or at least along those lines.

Comment: For this *specific* example, why can't you just use `data = [...kernel, ...kernel]`?

Comment: I've never used two spread operators together like that. What does it accomplish?

Comment: It makes `data` two copies of `kernel` e.g. `[...[1,2,3],...[1,2,3]] = [1,2,3,1,2,3]`

Comment: Well yes that does merge them how my output is shown, but not how I need them to merge. I'll need them to merge as explained because overlapping is required to complete a kde.

Comment: But with your sample data the two kernels don't overlap. One would run from 0-512 in data and the other from 513-1025.

Comment: Yeah haha, that's actually a good method. So essentially just cut the kernel in half, apply the first half before a `1` boolean value, then the centre kernel value over `1`, and then the second half past the `1` boolean value. Feel free to post that as a response. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you searching for. I also made an visual presentation how the result looks like

```js
const kernel = [0.0000010012331378948806, 0.0000010722046681969416, 0.000001147899227196217, 0.0000012286082418128176, 0.0000013146394976171826, 0.0000014063179475064513, 0.0000015039865533165654, 0.000001608007161276116, 0.0000017187614122055291, 0.0000018366516873606909, 0.000001962102090813225, 0.0000020955594692504055, 0.0000022374944700657156, 0.0000023884026385964733, 0.0000025488055553473936, 0.0000027192520140183837, 0.0000029003192411310286, 0.000003092614158021121, 0.000003296774685933875, 0.000003513471094924077, 0.0000037434073972252973, 0.000003987322785709955, 0.0000042459931180157695, 0.000004520232446863388, 0.000004810894597034758, 0.000005118874789422127, 0.0000054451113124928115, 0.000005790587241445476, 0.000006156332205258995, 0.000006543424201755123, 0.000006952991460711095, 0.000007386214354967505, 0.000007844327359380673, 0.00000832862105736654, 0.00000884044419467562, 0.0000093812057799243, 0.000009952377231288787, 0.000010555494568641264, 0.000011192160650276806, 0.000011864047453240681, 0.000012572898396121833, 0.00001332053070302737, 0.000014108837807296342, 0.000014939791793347624, 0.000015815445874887996, 0.000016737936907530242, 0.000017709487933690657, 0.00001873241075744663, 0.000019809108546842802]
const data = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

function mergeArr(arr1, arr2){
   let arr2Copy = arr2.map(el => el);
   let max = Math.max(...arr1);
   let indexMax = arr2Copy.indexOf(1);
   let sortedKernel = arr1.sort((a,b) => a - b);
   arr2Copy[indexMax] = max;
   let indexPosition = sortedKernel.length - 1;
   for(let i = indexMax; i >= 0; i--){
      if(indexPosition == 0){
         arr2Copy[i] = sortedKernel[indexPosition];
         continue;
      }
      arr2Copy[i] = sortedKernel[indexPosition];
      indexPosition--;
   }
   let reversedKernel = sortedKernel.reverse();
   for(let i = indexMax; i < arr2Copy.length; i++){
     if(indexPosition == arr2Copy.length - 1){
        break;
     }
     arr2Copy[i] = reversedKernel[indexPosition];
     indexPosition++;
     
   }
   return arr2Copy;
}

let result = mergeArr(kernel, data);
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    // The type of chart we want to create
    type: 'line',

    // The data for our dataset
    data: {
        labels: data,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Kernel',
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            data: result
        }]
    },

    // Configuration options go here
    options: {}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks for taking the time and nice visualisation.

Comment: @srb633 atm it works just for 1 point, didnt have time to create a function for multiple

Comment: Feel free to do so if you'd like but I think this has given me plenty of direction.